# Is there a standard end of lease time in Washington?

Tags: united-states, tenant, washington

I live in Seattle, and my lease is up soon, however it doesn't specify what time of day we have to be out of the unit, as my previous leases have.

I reviewed the RCW and local law, but could find no default time that a lease ends. I am curious to know before we talk with our landlord about it.

Comment: Do you mean time of day on the date that the lease terminates? The default would be midnight on the date of termination (due to the definition of a particular date on the calendar), although many leases vary that by agreement, and there may be some jurisdictions that vary that by law.

Comment: @ohwilleke Well, yes, not to sound sassy, but I'm not sure what other day could have been implied.

Comment: Thought you could have been talking about the end of a calendar month or something like that.

Comment: I'm sitting here shocked to learn that someone's lease specifies a time of day they have to be out of the unit at upon expiration. Never heard of that!

Comment: @A.fm. Really? My two prior leases both said noon.

Comment: Oh, and my newest one. So it's just one lease out of four that didn't specify noon

Answer (score 1):

### Midnight

You need to be out by the end of the period specified on the lease. Days end at midnight. The landlord (or new tenant) can take possession immediately after 24:00:00.

While this is not defined in the Washington [code](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx), this is the default situation at common law.